# Erlang and Antlr

Tags: erlang, code-generation, parsing, antlr

Is it possible to write an Antlr code generation target for Erlang?

Comment: of course , you can write any compiler with ANTLR but you need grammar for this language

Comment: if you mean you want to generate Erlang code to parse something using Antlr then yes it is possible, you can write something to generate whatever code you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean. If you mean you want to generate parser & lexer source files in Erlang, then no, this is not possible (at least, not out of the box*). Checkout the current list of targets for ANTLR: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets

* You could be the one implementing it, of course. But that's no trivial task!

Answer (score 1):

Erlang comes with its own [parse tools](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/parsetools/index.html). They use their own syntax though, so you cant take a grammar file from antlr.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, ANTLR is general purpose. If you really wanna do that, you should take a look at the [Core Erlang language specification](http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/cerl/doc/core_erlang-1.0.3.pdf). Be warned that it is quite old, but should be okay for a starter.

Comment: It is **much** nicer to generate Core erlang than normal erlang as it is a smaller simpler language. I do it for LFE. The main problem is that it is not as stable as erlang as they tend to view it as an internal compiler pass. I am trying to get them to change that though.